# Fill in missing periods in between periods where missing transactions

Tags: sql-server

With a lof of help from the community I have  been able to create a query that automatically adds new rows for project with accumulated number from previous row if there are no transactions. Unfortunately I came across on thing I would like to change. If there are no transactions in periods in between periods, those periods will be missing. I would like to fill those as well.

Example: Project 12345 GL:

| project | amount | period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10 | 202001 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202002 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202003 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202004 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202005 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202006 |
| 12345 | 10 | 202009 |

My code is the following:

```
DECLARE @d date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), 1);

;WITH src AS -- mostly your existing query
(
  SELECT project, 
     period,
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY project ORDER BY period DESC),
     amount = SUM(SUM(amount)) OVER 
              (PARTITION BY project ORDER BY period
               ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  FROM dbo.GLProject
  GROUP BY project, period
),
recur AS
(
  SELECT project, period = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, period), amount
  FROM src 
  WHERE rn = 1 AND period < @d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT project, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, period), amount
  FROM recur WHERE period < @d 
)
SELECT project, amount, period = CONVERT(char(6), period, 112)
FROM src
UNION ALL
SELECT project, amount, period = CONVERT(char(6), period, 112)
FROM recur
ORDER BY project, period;
```

I would like it to fill in the missing periods 202007 and 202008 as well. Like this:

| project | amount | period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10 | 202001 |
| 12345 | 20 | 202002 |
| 12345 | 30 | 202003 |
| 12345 | 40 | 202004 |
| 12345 | 50 | 202005 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202006 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202007 |
| 12345 | 60 | 202008 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202009 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202010 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202011 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202012 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202101 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202102 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202103 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202104 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202105 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202106 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202107 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202108 |
| 12345 | 70 | 202109 |

Any ideas on what to add to my query to solve this?

Fiddle for testing here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=615712cf89113c3a912268ed603fd2b4

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably won't believe me, but adding the requirement of filling in missing gaps actually drove a simpler solution.

```
DECLARE @d date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), 1);

;WITH total_range AS 
(
  SELECT project, period = MIN(period)
    FROM dbo.GLProject
    GROUP BY project
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT project, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, period)
  FROM total_range 
  WHERE period < @d
)
SELECT 
  tr.project, 
  amount = SUM(COALESCE(p.amount,0)) OVER (
             PARTITION BY tr.project ORDER BY tr.period
             -- ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING -- not strictly necessary here
           ), 
  period = CONVERT(char(6), tr.period, 112)
FROM total_range AS tr
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.GLProject AS p 
ON tr.project = p.project
AND tr.period = p.period;
```

- Example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c15b6a909eafb808f6def0acfdc2e61)